# Windows Mobile Native Code - jstring to LPCTSTR

Tags: java, c++, string, windows-mobile, java-native-interface

I have a Java app which needs to interact with the camera on a Windows Mobile device.  I have written the Java Code and the Native code and it all works fine.  The problem I am having now is that I want to start passing variables from Java to the Native code, e.g. the directory and file name to use for the photo.

The native code uses a `SHCAMERACAPTURE` object to interact with the camera and it expects the directory and filename to be specified using `LPCTSTR`s.  The string passed in is a jstring, which I can get to a `const char *` by calling:

```
const char *strDir=(jEnv)->GetStringUTFChars(dirName, 0);
```

But I am not sure how I can pass this to the the `SHCAMERACAPTURE` object because it cannot convert `const char *` to `LPCTSTR`. I tried a cast `(LPCTSTR)strDir` and it compiled, but I get an error when it runs (that it can't create the file).

I am a Java developer and pretty new to C++ etc. so I am really not too sure what I need to do to get my string into the native call.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try GetStringChars() instead of GetStringUTFChars() 
According to [this page](http://www.science.uva.nl/ict/ossdocs/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/string.html) it returns the Unicode String.

WindowsCE and Windows mobile use UNICODE exclusively so LPCTSTR
is actually LPCWSTR (Long Pointer to Const WideChar String)

```
SHCAMERACAPTURE shcc;
ZeroMemory(&shcc, sizeof(shcc));
shcc.cbSize = sizeof(shcc);
shcc.pszInitialDir = (TCHAR*)(jEnv)->GetStringChars(dirName, 0 ); 
shcc.pszDefaultFileName = (TCHAR*)(jEnv)->GetStringChars(defFileName, 0 );
```

I assume you want to provide a path and a filename. This is adapted from [this MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb160743.aspx)

Comment: `GetStringChars()` returns a `const jchar *`, so I still don't know how I can pass that to my native object?

Comment: What is `shcam.szFile`? and `GetStringChars()` does not take 0 arguments?  Can you explain what that line of code is trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: See updated answer. I did not remember well. Its been a few years away from WM. I am on a Mac and don't have access to VS2008 so it takes a while to find things.